# Ubuntu 14.04 Can't change desktop background and no files are visible on the desktop

Tags: 14.04, desktop-background

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 64bit: I can't change the desktop background from the native settings or using any "tweak-tools" I can find. And for some reason, I can right click on the files that should appear on my desktop, but that don't seem to be there?

Comment: You can still upload a screen shot somewhere on the internet and link to it your question. [Edit] your question to improve it with more info.

Comment: This typically happens when Nautils is disabled in Gnome-Tweak-Tool to handle the Desktop. Please check the output of this command: `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons`

Answer (score 4):

As @christian commented, you can use this command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons true
```